# Android lint shows up no issues in Sonarqube

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, sonarlint

I have setup my project to use with Sonarqube. I was using PMD and Checkstyle to run tests and all of them are successfully logged in Sonarqube console. But last day I decided to add Android lint rules also to my Quality profile. I have activated all Lint rules in a new profile and run the project. Now when I run the project, it is not showing up any errors or issues with this profile. When I run the lint locally I get about 400 issues. What could I be missing?

I am using Sonarqube plugin in Gradle and Sonarqube 6.2 on my server. My Sonarqube configuration is as follows

```
apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

sonarqube {
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    properties {
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.projectName", "MyProject"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.projectKey", "Testapplication"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.analysis.mode", "publish"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.language", "java"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main/"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.profile", "FindBugs"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://192.168.21.33:9000"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.login", "admin"
//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        property "sonar.password", "admin"
        property "sonar.exclusions","es.miguelprietos.testapplication/R.java"
        property "sonar.android.lint.report", "build/outputs/lint-results.xml"
        property "sonar.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/debug"
        property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/debug"


    }
}
```

I use below command to run my Sonar task (no parameters).

```
 ./gradlew sonarqube
```

Lint options configured in my Gradle is as below

```
   lintOptions {
        // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
        quiet true
        // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
        abortOnError false
        // if true, only report errors
        ignoreWarnings true
    }
```

Comment: Show your lintOptions in app's build.gradle. Is your lint reports empty?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @shmakova Added lint options configured in my app level build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "./gradlew lint" is what you are looking for.
As describe here, it will generate the missing XML report.
Be carful, it can generate a report for each build variant (Debug by default will generate build/outputs/lint-results-debug.xml). So you can call lintDebug, lintRelease... dependings on your build variant.

And change your report file-name accordingly to the generated file.

Answer (score 1):

Try not ignore warnings:

```
lintOptions {
    // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
    quiet true
    // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
    abortOnError false
    // do not ignore warnings
    warningsAsErrors true
}
```